# C++ defining class member from an abstract type

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, abstract, abstract-data-type

I am trying to move some code from C# to C++ and I am trying to find the best way to implement a class hierarchy.
In C#, in a derived class you can define a class member variable from the abstract base class type. However, as I searched through my C++ resources, it seems I can only define 
a pointer or reference variabel from an abstract type in another class (otherwise the compiler shows: "cannot instantiate abstract class"), but that could have issues with the lifetime of the defined objects as the lifetime is handled outside of the class using it. Any suggestion on how such a inheritance hierarchy should be implemented when C# code is mapped to C++?

```
Class Person
{
  public:
    virtual double getSalary() = 0;
  private:
    int rank;
}

Class Teacher : public Person
{
  public:
     double getSalary();
  private:
     Person manager;        /*<-- Compile error: error C2259: 'Person' : cannot instantiate abstract class */
}
```

Comment: C++ and C# are _completely_ different languages - you can't simply move code from one to the other.

Comment: You want to use a pointer or reference. Like `Person* manager;`. That way, the object `manager` points at is either directly of class Person (although in this example that cannot be) or of a class that inherits from Person. `manager = new Teacher;` would thus be legal.

Comment: I added C# part to give context on my question. The main question really is how can you define a class member variable from an abstract base type in a derived class. I guess that is a legitimate question for an OO PL like C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct answer to your question: you can't define a class member variable of an abstract type. In C++, a member is mostly defined by memory size and, since an inherited class can require a different amount of memory, that is not possible.

However, you can use pointers or references.

In your case:

```
class Teacher : public Person
{
    public:
        double getSalary();
    private:
        Person* manager;
}
```

This stores a pointer to `Person`, and since `Teacher` *is-a* `Person`, an object of type `Teacher` would be a legal target.

Exemplary use: we create a setter

```
Teacher::set_manager(Person* manager)
{
    this->manager = manager;
}
```

and call it like

```
Teacher a;
Teacher* b = new Teacher;
a.set_manager(b);
```

(I used a setter as the most simple example, not necessarily because I'd recommend to go like that.)

Also possible:

```
Teacher a;
Person* b = new Teacher;
a.set_manager(b);
```

(`a` needs to be a `Teacher`, though, since we need the method `set_manager`, if we don't want to cast)

An even better thing to do here is to use smart pointers, by the way. Read into `std::shared_ptr` and related for that. It would look like

```
std::shared_ptr<Person> manager;
```

Important difference here: if you are accustomed to garbage daemons, you need to free the memory of a raw pointer manually, while smart pointers free the memory automatically when nothing points at an object any more.

That said, you seem to think that the languages are more alike than they are. My recommendation is to start from the beginning, with a basic tutorial in C++, even if you should happen to be an accomplished C# programmer.